# How to Pivot this resultset in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help me to pivot the dataset ?

```
SELECT 
    [ParentFormId], [FieldName], value, [RowValidTo],
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [RowValidTo] DESC) AS Sno
FROM 
    [asite].[viewK80FormField]
CROSS APPLY 
    STRING_SPLIT ([FieldValue], ',') AS t
WHERE 
    ParentFormId = '30571360' 
    AND FieldName IN ('docid', 'docrev', 'docPublishDate')
```

[SQL Server, result set to be pivoted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qasXT.png)

Attempted `PIVOT` query:

```
WITH CTE_DocAttri AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             [ParentFormId], [FieldName], value, [RowValidTo],
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [FieldName] ORDER BY [RowValidTo] DESC) AS Sno
         FROM 
             [asite].[viewK80FormField]
         CROSS APPLY
             STRING_SPLIT ([FieldValue], ',') AS t
         WHERE
             ParentFormId = '30571360' 
             AND FieldName IN ('docid', 'docrev', 'docPublishDate')
        ) AS source_table
    PIVOT 
        (MAX([Value]) 
             FOR [FieldName] IN (docPublishDate, DocID, DocRev)
        ) AS PivotTABLE
)
SELECT 
    ParentFormId, docPublishDate, DocID, DocRev 
FROM
    CTE_DocAttri
```

Result for the pivot query  (Getting only one row)

| ParentFormId | docPublishDate | DocID | DocRev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30571360 | 28/04/2021 | 53079864 | 2 |

Comment: You need to provide the desired results.   Otherwise we're guessing as to the rows and columns.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you for the reply. I need the columns like 

ParentformID | DocID | PubDate |

Comment: Please avoid image and post the sample data and desired result as formatted text. Please also include the attempted pivoting query

Comment: @Squirrel Update my question please check.

Comment: What is that last table ? current result or expected result ?

Comment: What is the data type of the value column?  This seems to be a mix of dates and integers.  If it is a varchar, then max on the dates will not give you your expected result, since it will return the value with the highest day part, not the highest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpDpn.png)Got the resultset atlast,

```
WITH cte_docattri
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT [parentformid],
                        [fieldname],
                        value,
                        [rowvalidto],
                        Row_number()
                          OVER (
                            partition BY [parentformid], fieldname
                            ORDER BY [rowvalidto] DESC) AS Sno
                 FROM   [asite].[viewk80formfield]
                        CROSS apply String_split ([fieldvalue], ',') AS t
                 WHERE  parentformid = '30571360'
                        AND fieldname IN ( 'docid', 'docrev', 'docPublishDate' )
                )AS
                source_table
                PIVOT ( Max([value])
                      FOR [fieldname] IN (docpublishdate,
                                          docid,
                                          docrev) ) AS pivottable)
SELECT sno,
       parentformid,
       docpublishdate,
       docid,
       docrev
FROM   cte_docattri
```